# Can't output $_COOKIE in drupal 6 for demo.exampl.com?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, session-cookies

I'm not able to echo `$_COOKIE` variable for not logged-in users and for logged-in user on certain pages.

For example when I am on `http://www.example.com/?abc=true` I am able to output `$_COOKIE` variable, but when I move to any other page I can't access this variable. This problem is occurring in drupal6 with varnish setting on.

Comment: Varnish blocks cookies by default. You need to configure varnish to pass cookies to backend. Disable varnish to check is it the case.

Comment: This is happen for certain pages. Like for home and some internal pages. On simple node i can output cookie value. Is there a way to unset or disable cookie value on certain pages only using varnish.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because Varnish is caching only some of the pages and this is causing the issue. Once we removed varnish the changes start reflecting as usual.